# Basic logical operator question

Tags: c, operators

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int k=5;
    if(++k < 5 && k++ / 5 || ++k <= 8)
    {
         printf("%d",k);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Why is the output 7 and not 8?(I am a beginner in programming so please bear with me.)

Comment: I'm fairly certain that the output of this particular code is undefined. Doing multiple increments on the same variable in the same statement is a classic "undefined behavior" of C and C++. It could blow up the sun and still be "correct".

Comment: because undefined behavior, which means *anything* can happen from printing 7 or 8 to wiping your harddrive

Comment: @Telastyn: There is a sequence point at `&&` and `||`, so this code has well-defined semantics.

Comment: @mafso - yes, another (unmigrated?) comment pointed that out.

Comment: @Telastyn: Never mind :) I just wanted to correct this to prevent reinforcing the "Oh please, not again a 'why is `a++ + ++a` undefined' question" reaction many people here will probably feel like at a first glance (me included).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Operator precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) and logical expression [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

The `&&` in your logical condition binds more tightly than `||`, so your conditional is equivalent to:

```
((++k<5 && k++/5) || ++k<=8)
```

It's easier to read code when it is presented in a structured way, like this:

```
int main() {
    int k=5;
    if ((++k<5 && k++/5) || ++k<=8) {
        printf("%d",k);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And now a blow-by-blow of the execution.

1. `k` starts at 5.
2. `++k<5` advances `k` to 6, which is *not* `<5`.
3. The second half of the `&&` expression is never evaluated, because `0 && ANYTHING == 0`.
4. Because the left hand side of the `||` is 0, the right hand side is *not* short circuited. It must be evaluated.
5. `++k<=8` advances `k` to 7, which *is* `<=8`.
6. Total conditional evaluates to 1 because right hand side of `||` is 1.
7. The "then" clause of the `if` statement is executed.
8. Current value of `k`, which is 7, is printed.
9. The program returns 0, and terminates.

It's also worth noting that the second half of your `&&` clause is perhaps not doing what you intended. `k++/5` is integer division, and since `k>5` at all times, `k++/5` will always be `>=1` and thus always true.

Comment: You're welcome @user147699. If you think this answers your question, please "accept" the answer by clicking the checkmark near its upper left.